# Update elements in the nested dictionary of varying depth via given path in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to update the specific **elements** only with the given path dynamically it can be done by selecting my_dict['m1]['m2']['m3'] = 100 but i want dynamic approach

```
paths = ['m1.m2.m3','m1.m2.m4','ml2.2']
```

Dictionary

```
my_dict= {
    'm1': {
        'm2': {
            'm3': 55,
            'm4' : 75
            }
        },
    'ml2': ['a', 'b', 'c']
}
```

for the first path (m1.m2.m3) I want to update 55 by 100 or any other number. In the dict also the last path i.e, go to the ml2 and update the 2'nd  element 'b' by 'a' or any other value

Comment: What you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

As you can imagine, such problem may require some sort of **recursivity**.

Consider the following function:

```py
def get_nested(data, *args):
    if args and data:
        element  = args[0]
        if element:
            value = data.get(element)
            return value if len(args) == 1 else get_nested(value, *args[1:])
```

You can now get any depth in your dictionary by doing something like:

```
get_nested(dictionary, first_level_key, second_level_key, key_you_want)
```

By following the same principle, you can set (update) a dictionary at any depth like so:

```py
def set_nested(data, to_set, *args):
    if args and data:
        key = args[0]
        if key:
            if len(args) == 1:
                data[key] = to_set
            else:
                data[key] = set_nested(data[key], to_set, *args[1:])
    return data
```

That works in the following example:

```py
d = {
    'a': {
        'b': {
            'c': 0
        }
    }
}

set_nested(d, 1, 'a', 'b', 'c')
# return: {'a': {'b': {'c': 1}}}
```

These functions give you the logic behind the recursive algorithms needed to fulfill your requirements. You can then easily modify them to add your own logic. Such as the fact of using strings instead of function list parameter.

Have a nice day

Comment: It is still a static approach I'm not able to enter the list or tuple in the path

Comment: @SanskarJaiswal These simple recursive functions give you the algorithm required by such operation. You can easily modify it to fulfill your needs, with for example `path.split`

Answer (score 0):

A very clean way of achieving this is by using the built-in `functools.reduce` function:

```
from functools imnport reduce

results = [reduce(dict.get, [my_dict] + path.split('.')) for path in paths]
```

However, this works only if your dict contains only dicts, and the sub-dicts contain only dicts, and so on. Here is an example with:

```
>>> paths = ['m1.m2.m3','m1.m2.m4','ml2.2']
>>> my_dict= {
...     'm1': {
...         'm2': {
...             'm3': 55,
...             'm4' : 75
...             }
...         },
...     'ml2': {'0': 'a', '1': 'b', '2': 'c'}
... }
>>> results = [reduce(dict.get, [my_dict] + path.split('.')) for path in paths]
>>> results
[55, 75, 'c']
```

However, you might have lists in your data, so this approach won't work as long as you don't get rid of them. Therefore you could use a function slightly more complicated than `dict.get`:

```
from functools import reduce

results = [reduce(lambda o, k: o[int(k)] if isinstance(o, list) else o[k],
                  [my_dict] + path.split('.')) for path in paths]
```

Now everything works with your original data!

```
>>> paths = ['m1.m2.m3','m1.m2.m4','ml2.2']
>>> my_dict= {
...     'm1': {
...         'm2': {
...             'm3': 55,
...             'm4' : 75
...             }
...         },
...     'ml2': ['a', 'b', 'c']
... }
>>> results = [reduce(lambda o, k: o[int(k)] if isinstance(o, list) else o[k],
...                   [my_dict] + path.split('.')) for path in paths]
>>> results
[55, 75, 'c']
```

Comment: But how can I update the elements it only gave me the value? How fo I change it to some other value.

Comment: @SanskarJaiswal The second approach works with you data. Please mark my answer as accepted if you think it is useful

Comment: I can only get the values by your method but I cannot change it to any other value